# PANIC=runtime error: index out of range

Tags: arrays, go, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following code, but i can't figure out why the error:`PANIC=runtime error: index out of range is happening`

```
type Board struct {
    Tboard  [9]string
    Player1 Player
    Player2 Player
}
func makeBoard() *Board {
    b := &Board{Tboard: [9]string{}}
    for x := 0; x < len(b.Tboard); x++ {
        b.Tboard[x] = E // E = "[ ]"
        fmt.Println(b.Tboard[x])
    }
    fmt.Println(len(b.Tboard)) // => 9
    fmt.Print("Error: ")
    fmt.Println(b)        // => Error: %!v(PANIC=runtime error: index out of range)
    fmt.Println(b.Tboard) // => [[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]]
    return b
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace when the program panics.

Comment: It seems to work fine on the playground http://play.golang.org/p/_P_BiKLKS8 . My guess is that maybe it's trying to convert Player to a string when printing the struct and there's something weird in Player? Do you have Player.String() defined?

Comment: i didn't remember that i had defined Board.String() and there was the problem, thanks